# Invalid access to packet while iterating over packet in eBPF program ， with “bpf_trace_printk”

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I'm working on an eBPF program using the BCC framework to analyze HTTP requests. The program is designed to intercept TCP packets on port 8000 and search for a specific pattern ("cmd=") in the payload. Below is the simplified version of my eBPF code:

```c
#include <uapi/linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>

#define TCP_PORT_HTTP 8000
#define MAX_ITERATIONS 100 
#define MAX_CMD_LENGTH 100


int xdp_search_http_request(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;

    if ((void *)(eth + 1) > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;

    if (eth->h_proto != htons(ETH_P_IP))
        return XDP_PASS;

    struct iphdr *ip = (void *)eth + sizeof(*eth);
    if ((void *)(ip + 1) > data_end || ip->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
        return XDP_PASS;

    struct tcphdr *tcp = (void *)ip + ip->ihl * 4;
    if ((void *)(tcp + 1) > data_end || tcp->dest != htons(TCP_PORT_HTTP))
        return XDP_PASS;

    unsigned char *payload = (unsigned char *)tcp + (tcp->doff * 4);
    if ((void *)(payload + 1) > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;

    unsigned char *end = data_end;
    int cmd_value_start = 0;

    // Simple search for "cmd=" in the payload
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS && (payload + i + 4) <= end; i++) {
        if (payload[i] == 'c' && payload[i+1] == 'm' && payload[i+2] == 'd' && payload[i+3] == '=') {
            // Found the "cmd=" string
            bpf_trace_printk("Found cmd parameter in HTTP request\\n");
            // Move the pointer to the value part of "cmd="
            cmd_value_start = i + 4;              


        int j = 0;
        char cmd [100] = {0};
        for (j = cmd_value_start; (j < (cmd_value_start + MAX_CMD_LENGTH)) && ((payload + j) < end) && payload[j] != ' ' && payload[j] != '&'; j++) {
            cmd[j - cmd_value_start] = payload[j];
        }

        bpf_trace_printk("cmd value: %s", cmd);

            break;  // Exit after finding the first occurrence
        }
    }
    



    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

When I attempt to load and execute this program, I encounter the following error:

```
bpf: Failed to load program: Permission denied
; void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
0: (61) r6 = *(u32 *)(r1 +4)
; void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
1: (61) r7 = *(u32 *)(r1 +0)
; if ((void *)(eth + 1) > data_end)
2: (bf) r1 = r7
3: (07) r1 += 14
; if ((void *)(eth + 1) > data_end)
4: (2d) if r1 > r6 goto pc+41
 R1_w=pkt(id=0,off=14,r=14,imm=0) R6_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=14,imm=0) R10=fp0
; if (eth->h_proto != htons(ETH_P_IP))
5: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r7 +12)
6: (71) r2 = *(u8 *)(r7 +13)
7: (67) r2 <<= 8
8: (4f) r2 |= r1
; if (eth->h_proto != htons(ETH_P_IP))
9: (55) if r2 != 0x8 goto pc+36
 R1_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R2_w=inv8 R6_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=14,imm=0) R10=fp0
; if ((void *)(ip + 1) > data_end || ip->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
10: (bf) r1 = r7
11: (07) r1 += 34
; if ((void *)(ip + 1) > data_end || ip->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
12: (2d) if r1 > r6 goto pc+33
 R1=pkt(id=0,off=34,r=34,imm=0) R2=inv8 R6=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R10=fp0
; if ((void *)(ip + 1) > data_end || ip->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
13: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r7 +23)
; if ((void *)(ip + 1) > data_end || ip->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
14: (55) if r1 != 0x6 goto pc+31
 R1_w=inv6 R2=inv8 R6=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R10=fp0
; 
15: (bf) r1 = r7
16: (07) r1 += 14
; struct tcphdr *tcp = (void *)ip + ip->ihl * 4;
17: (71) r8 = *(u8 *)(r1 +0)
; struct tcphdr *tcp = (void *)ip + ip->ihl * 4;
18: (67) r8 <<= 2
19: (57) r8 &= 60
; struct tcphdr *tcp = (void *)ip + ip->ihl * 4;
20: (0f) r1 += r8
last_idx 20 first_idx 12
regs=100 stack=0 before 19: (57) r8 &= 60
regs=100 stack=0 before 18: (67) r8 <<= 2
regs=100 stack=0 before 17: (71) r8 = *(u8 *)(r1 +0)
; if ((void *)(tcp + 1) > data_end || tcp->dest != htons(TCP_PORT_HTTP))
21: (bf) r2 = r1
22: (07) r2 += 20
; if ((void *)(tcp + 1) > data_end || tcp->dest != htons(TCP_PORT_HTTP))
23: (2d) if r2 > r6 goto pc+22
 R1=pkt(id=1,off=14,r=34,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R2=pkt(id=1,off=34,r=34,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R6=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R8=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R10=fp0
; if ((void *)(tcp + 1) > data_end || tcp->dest != htons(TCP_PORT_HTTP))
24: (69) r2 = *(u16 *)(r1 +2)
; if ((void *)(tcp + 1) > data_end || tcp->dest != htons(TCP_PORT_HTTP))
25: (55) if r2 != 0x401f goto pc+20
 R1=pkt(id=1,off=14,r=34,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R2_w=inv16415 R6=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R8=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R10=fp0
; unsigned char *payload = (unsigned char *)tcp + (tcp->doff * 4);
26: (69) r5 = *(u16 *)(r1 +12)
; unsigned char *payload = (unsigned char *)tcp + (tcp->doff * 4);
27: (77) r5 >>= 2
28: (57) r5 &= 60
; unsigned char *payload = (unsigned char *)tcp + (tcp->doff * 4);
29: (0f) r1 += r5
last_idx 29 first_idx 23
regs=20 stack=0 before 28: (57) r5 &= 60
regs=20 stack=0 before 27: (77) r5 >>= 2
regs=20 stack=0 before 26: (69) r5 = *(u16 *)(r1 +12)
; if ((void *)(payload + 1) > data_end)
30: (bf) r2 = r1
31: (07) r2 += 1
; if ((void *)(payload + 1) > data_end)
32: (2d) if r2 > r6 goto pc+13
 R1=pkt(id=2,off=14,r=15,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R2=pkt(id=2,off=15,r=15,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R5=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R6=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R8=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R10=fp0
33: (07) r1 += 4
34: (2d) if r1 > r6 goto pc+11
 R1_w=pkt(id=2,off=18,r=18,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R2=pkt(id=2,off=15,r=18,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R5=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R6=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R8=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R10=fp0
; for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS && (payload + i + 4) <= end; i++) {
35: (bf) r2 = r8
36: (0f) r2 += r5
37: (bf) r1 = r7
38: (0f) r1 += r2
last_idx 38 first_idx 32
regs=4 stack=0 before 37: (bf) r1 = r7
regs=4 stack=0 before 36: (0f) r2 += r5
regs=24 stack=0 before 35: (bf) r2 = r8
regs=120 stack=0 before 34: (2d) if r1 > r6 goto pc+11
regs=120 stack=0 before 33: (07) r1 += 4
regs=120 stack=0 before 32: (2d) if r2 > r6 goto pc+13
 R1_rw=pkt(id=2,off=14,r=0,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R2_rw=pkt(id=2,off=15,r=0,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R5_rw=invP(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R6_r=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_r=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R8_r=invP(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R10=fp0
parent didn't have regs=120 stack=0 marks
last_idx 31 first_idx 23
regs=120 stack=0 before 31: (07) r2 += 1
regs=120 stack=0 before 30: (bf) r2 = r1
regs=120 stack=0 before 29: (0f) r1 += r5
regs=120 stack=0 before 28: (57) r5 &= 60
regs=120 stack=0 before 27: (77) r5 >>= 2
regs=120 stack=0 before 26: (69) r5 = *(u16 *)(r1 +12)
regs=100 stack=0 before 25: (55) if r2 != 0x401f goto pc+20
regs=100 stack=0 before 24: (69) r2 = *(u16 *)(r1 +2)
regs=100 stack=0 before 23: (2d) if r2 > r6 goto pc+22
 R1_rw=pkt(id=1,off=14,r=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R2_rw=pkt(id=1,off=34,r=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R6_r=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_r=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R8_rw=invP(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R10=fp0
parent didn't have regs=100 stack=0 marks
last_idx 22 first_idx 12
regs=100 stack=0 before 22: (07) r2 += 20
regs=100 stack=0 before 21: (bf) r2 = r1
regs=100 stack=0 before 20: (0f) r1 += r8
regs=100 stack=0 before 19: (57) r8 &= 60
regs=100 stack=0 before 18: (67) r8 <<= 2
regs=100 stack=0 before 17: (71) r8 = *(u8 *)(r1 +0)
39: (b7) r9 = 0
40: (05) goto pc+7
; if (payload[i] == 'c' && payload[i+1] == 'm' && payload[i+2] == 'd' && payload[i+3] == '=') {
48: (bf) r2 = r1
49: (0f) r2 += r9
last_idx 49 first_idx 48
regs=200 stack=0 before 48: (bf) r2 = r1
 R1_rw=pkt(id=4,off=0,r=0,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R2_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c)) R5=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R6=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R8=inv(id=3,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R9_rw=invP0 R10=fp0
parent didn't have regs=200 stack=0 marks
last_idx 40 first_idx 32
regs=200 stack=0 before 40: (05) goto pc+7
regs=200 stack=0 before 39: (b7) r9 = 0
50: (71) r3 = *(u8 *)(r2 +14)
invalid access to packet, off=14 size=1, R2(id=4,off=14,r=0)
R2 offset is outside of the packet
processed 44 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 4 peak_states 4 mark_read 2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/parallels/Desktop/test5.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/parallels/Desktop/test5.py", line 71, in main
    xdp_func = b.load_func("xdp_search_http_request", BPF.XDP)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 526, in load_func
    raise Exception("Failed to load BPF program %s: %s" %
Exception: Failed to load BPF program b'xdp_search_http_request': Permission denied
```

Interestingly, if I comment out the bpf_trace_printk("cmd value: %s", cmd); line, the program loads and executes without any issues. This leads me to believe that the problem might be related to the usage of bpf_trace_printk, especially with formatting strings.

I've ensured that the necessary kernel capabilities are enabled and have tried running the program with elevated privileges, but the issue persists. I'm currently using [Linux kernel version, BCC version, and any other relevant environment details].

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can offer insights into why bpf_trace_printk might be causing the program to fail to load? Any suggestions on how to resolve this or alternative approaches for debugging within eBPF programs would be greatly appreciated.

I am using 5.15.0-100-generic kernel in ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR.** The verifier is loosing track of `payload + i` between when you bound check it and when you use it. I'd advise making that it's own variable.

---

**Verifier Error Explanation**

```
invalid access to packet, off=14 size=1, R2(id=4,off=14,r=0)
R2 offset is outside of the packet
```

Here, the verifier is complaining that you are trying to access the packet at offset 14 (`off=14`), but you haven't checked that the packet is actually big enough (`r0`).

That may be surprising because you did check the packet's length. We can see the corresponding bytecode at instruction 34:

```
33: (07) r1 += 4
34: (2d) if r1 > r6 goto pc+11
 R1_w=pkt(id=2,off=18,r=18,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R2=pkt(id=2,off=15,r=18,umax_value=120,var_off=(0x0; 0x7c),s32_max_value=124,u32_max_value=124) R5=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R6=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=34,imm=0) R8=inv(id=0,umax_value=60,var_off=(0x0; 0x3c)) R10=fp0
```

Here `r1` is `payload + i + 4` and it is compared with `r6`, the pointer to the end of the packet. The packet's length is then correctly updated in the verifier state: `r1`'s range is set to 18 (`r=18`).

However, when preparing the memory access for `payload[i] == 'c'`, the compiler recomputes the pointer from scratch instead of using the just-verified `r1` register. It thus loses track of the packet bounds.

---

**Why does `bpf_trace_printk` Have an Impact?**

If you remove calls to `bpf_trace_printk`, then the `cmd` variable is never used. The compiler therefore optimizes it away, along with any code to update it. In practice, that probably means that almost all your code is optimized away.

---

**Solution**

Working around this will probably require several iterations to "knead" your code into something that the verifier is able to track. I'd start by making `payload + i` its own iteration variable:

```c
max_ptr = payload + MAX_ITERATIONS;
for (int ptr = payload; ptr < max_ptr && (ptr + 4) <= end; ptr++) {
    if (*ptr == 'c' && ...
```